# Get the BigQuery Table creator and Google Storage Bucket Creator Details

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to identify the users who created tables in BigQuery.
Is there any command line or API that would provide this information. I know that audit logs do provide this information, but I was looking for a command line which could do the job so that i could wrap this in a shell script and run them against all the tables at one time. Same for Google Storage Buckets as well. I did try

`gsutil iam get gs://my-bkt` and looked for  "role": "roles/storage.admin" role, but I do not find the admin role with all buckets. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for audit logs.  BigQuery tables don't report metadata about the original resource creator, so scanning via tables.list or inspecting the ACLs don't really expose who created the resource, only who currently has access.

What's the use case?  You could certainly export the audit logs back into BigQuery and query for table creation events going forward, but that's not exactly the same.

Comment: Use case is that - there are several tables created in a project and they were created like couple of years back. Those tables are huge in size ( > 700 GB) and we wanted to either delete them or see if we can apply some retention rules on the tables by contacting the owner. Hence was looking if there was an easier way. Same with GCS as well. This is a very useful feature to have handy on the table metadata to identify who was the creator. I know Bigquery SQL queries didnt have this feature either, but in the new UI, under project queries, you can readily see the user triggering the query.

Comment: The audit logs would help identify if anyone is currently accessing the resource, so even absent the creator identity you could determine if any consumers remain.  Setting retention policy doesn't typically require the creator identity, only that you have sufficient rights on the resource in question (e.g. the bigquery table).

Answer (score 0):

You can find it out using [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs). You can access them both via [Console/Log Explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/) or using `gcloud` tool from the CLI.

The log filter that you're interested in is this one:

```
resource.type = ("bigquery_project" OR "bigquery_dataset")
logName="projects/YOUR_PROJECT/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
protoPayload.methodName = "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.InsertTable"
protoPayload.resourceName = "projects/YOUR_PROJECT/datasets/curb_tracking/tables/YOUR_TABLE"
```

If you want to run it from the command line, you'd do something like this:

```
gcloud logging read \
'
resource.type = ("bigquery_project" OR "bigquery_dataset")
logName="projects/YOUR_PROJECT/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
protoPayload.methodName = "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.InsertTable"
protoPayload.resourceName = "projects/YOUR_PROJECT/datasets/curb_tracking/tables/YOUR_TABLE"
'\
 --limit 10
```

You can then post-process the output to find out who created the table. Look for `principalEmail` field.